# WAMP Apache Open port

Tags: apache, wamp

I'm trying to open port 8080 of localhost, but it doesn't work, in my httpd-vhosts archive i have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/demostration"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Just to check, you are using the port in your address like this arn't you `localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your apache installation is listening on port 8080.

To listen on both port `80` and `8080`, use

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

Comment: I fixed it, the problem is really stupis, because i wrote Listen 8000, and I didn't see it. Whatever, thank you.